# How to customize existing workflow.aspx page?

Tags: workflow, application-pages

I want to customize existing file in Sharepoint 2010 directory: TEMPLATE\LAYOUT\existing\workflow.aspx

How can I achieve this?

My purpose is to hide the section 'Start a New Workflow', it is OK to use javascript or css to hide this section in browser side.

Much thanks

Comment: why do you want to hide it? isn't it enough to prevent the workflow from being started manually? (it won't show here anymore)

Comment: My workflow is started using code, I don't want users to start workflow from here(I have many workflows with on list, so users might be confused)

Comment: I think that the proper way would be to set the workflows not to be started manually

Comment: I like your question, and found it while searching for the same thing. I see you're getting a lot of negative hits. For my own sake, I was interested in adding some big "First Time User?" links on the page to give folks a bit of guidance on the workflow.aspx page. There are, imho, valid use cases for being able to mod the worfkow.aspx page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to put the workflow to not start manually, you dont need to do custom actions for that.

Comment: yeah, I totally agree with you and this is what I told the OP in a comment

Comment: You are right, I now disable the manual start option

Answer (score 1):

There is an out-of-the-box way how to prevent users who have the Edit Items permission to start a workflow.

[According to Start a workflow instance](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662540%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

> **Permissions needed to start a workflow**  By default, users who have the Edit Items permission can start a workflow. If you specify that
>   Manage List permissions are required to start the workflow, only list
>   administrators (that is, anyone with Manage Lists permission or the
>   Design permission-level) can start an instance of the workflow. Most
>   workflows do not require this restriction. However, you can use the
>   Manage Lists option for workflows that contain tasks, such as
>   workflows that delete documents, which you want only certain people to
>   perform.

After enabling `Require Manage Lists Permissions to start the workflow`

[image]

users with `Contribute` permissions wont be able to start a workflow.

Answer (score -2):

Finally I added a custom action to inject my css to every file, in my css file I hide the div which I don't need.

```
  <CustomAction Id="ReferCssSiteCol" 
                Location="ScriptLink" 
                ScriptBlock="document.write('&lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; After=&quot;Corev15.css&quot;  type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;../_layouts/MyProject/main.css&quot;&gt;&lt;/' + 'link&gt;');"
                Sequence="202" />
```

in my main.css:

```
form[action*="Workflow.aspx"] #MSO_ContentTable #ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2){
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: even though this trick works, I would recommend you to handle it via permissions